# A question in Spanish

Tags: discussion

I've only ever seen questions in English on AU before, so [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600691/problemas-con-el-audio-ubuntu-14-04-despues-de-actualizacion-marzo-2015) caught my eye. Should I translate it to English while editing it?

Or ask the OP to write in English? I can't help thinking that if he could speak English, he'd have asked in English. On the other hand, if he can't speak English, then he's not going to be able to understand an English answer.

Comment: Unbelievably, the site only suggested the Meta post about non-English questions _after_ I'd posted!

Comment: Also, someone else has already run it through a translation service...